# Effective Object Mapping

Tags: java, object

I am trying to write a scripted AI; and ran into this problem. In the following base class, how can I tell `x` that it can just as well expect a `write` reference?

```
class Node <T0, T1, T2> {
    Node() {
        // More missing non-relevance.
    }
    T0 write(T1 x) {
        T0.write(x.read());
    }
    T0 write(T2 x) {
        T0.write(x.read());
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Here is the error:

```
Parser.java:181: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method read()
location: class java.lang.Object
```

P.S. Or should I just do this in C++ function pointers.

Comment: Which `x`? What `write` reference?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? Could not understand it o.õ

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What do you mean by "tell `x` it can just as well expect a `write` reference"? And if you're interested in Java solutions (which I'm assuming given the code and the tag), why the mention of C++ function pointers?

Comment: (See the edit) I am trying to overcome the error of a Java class not being properly compiled; with references which do exist in both of the 'write' functions.

Comment: @Mac, switching to C is a given solution.

Comment: Java generics are (apart from the syntax) completely different to C++ templates or .NET generics; read about how they work and it may make it clear why your code doesn't compile. The [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) is a good resource for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java you would need an Interface/class that has the read method. You ether use a standard one (perhaps x is an `OutputStream` implementation?). Otherwise you would create your own interface. (Had to interpret a lot, but perhaps the code below is helpful)

```
class Node <T0 extends OutputStream, T1 extends InputStream> {

  T0 to;


  Node(T0 to) {
    this.to = to;
  }

  T0 write(T1 x) throws IOException {
    to.write(x.read());
    return to;
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks what I may need to be doing.